# How do I fix my Discord bot being offline?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I got recently interested in discord bots coding and I don't know what the problem is with this error, I tried different solutions I can find but all of them are not working and my bot is still offline on the server.

```
Error: Invalid transport, must be an object with a log method.
  at new LegacyTransportStream (C:\Users\redacted\Desktop\NinyaBot\node_modules\winston-transport\legacy.js:18:11)
  at DerivedLogger.add (C:\Users\redacted\Desktop\NinyaBot\node_modules\winston\lib\winston\logger.js:345:11)
  at Object.winston.<computed> [as add] (C:\Users\redacted\Desktop\NinyaBot\node_modules\winston\lib\winston.js:110:68)
  at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\redacted\Desktop\NinyaBot\bot.js:6:8)
  at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
  at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
  at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
  at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
  at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47
```

- this is the code i used that i found online.

  ```
  var Discord = require('discord.io');
  var logger = require('winston');
  var auth = require('./auth.json');
  // Configure logger settings
  logger.remove(logger.transports.Console);
  logger.add(logger.transports.Console, {
      colorize: true
  });
  logger.level = 'debug';
  // Initialize Discord Bot
  var bot = new Discord.Client({
     token: auth.token,
     autorun: true
  });
  bot.on('ready', function (evt) {
      logger.info('Connected');
      logger.info('Logged in as: ');
      logger.info(bot.username + ' - (' + bot.id + ')');
  });
  bot.on('message', function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
      // Our bot needs to know if it will execute a command
      // It will listen for messages that will start with `!`
      if (message.substring(0, 1) == '!') {
          var args = message.substring(1).split(' ');
          var cmd = args[0];

          args = args.splice(1);
          switch(cmd) {
             // !ping
              case 'ping':
                  bot.sendMessage({
                      to: channelID,
                      message: 'Pong!'
                  });
              break;
              // Just add any case commands if you want to..
           }
       }
  });
  ```

Comment: Showing us your code may help. Try to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You are getting the error from "winston-transport\legacy.js"
So, your "winston" version might be a problem.
Can you provide the version of "winston" you are using

Answer (score 1):

The error showed in console is about line 6, however maybe is not what makes the
bot appears offline.

```js
logger.add(logger.transports.Console, {
    colorize: true
});
```

And should be fixed with something like

```js
logger.add(new logger.transports.Console({
    format: winston.format.combine(
        winston.format.colorize(),
        winston.format.simple()
    )
}));
```

Watch to `new` word. Now transports require a new object to work and for colorize you can set it combining the formats.

Here you can find more info about it https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston#common-transport-options

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using discord.js https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/#creating-the-bot-file
Use this code and it works just fine:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.login('your-token-goes-here');
```